# how to save Page in Android

Tags: java, android

I have create application In android and displaying data in web view i want to save that page how to do this plz help me i m not able to do this just send me code for that or u have dummy. Example related that kindly Post or else tell me logic how we ll do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use saveWebArchive method to save page to a file on local system, see:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveWebArchive%28java.lang.String%29